# pandas : extracting column1's value at column2th position

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns one string column & One integer column.

```
column1  column2
 abcdef        2
  gtihj        4
  jiuwq        3
```

I want another column3 with the column1's value at col2 position, something like this

```
column1    column2   column3    
abcdef     2         b
gtihj      4         h
jiuwq      3         u
```

I tried the following code

```
result['column1'].str.get(result['column2'])
```

but getting following error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is generated because `str.get` needs a scalar index, not a list/iterable of indexes (it doesn't understand that kind of input nor does it know what to do with it).

In this situation, a *list comprehension* comes to the rescue -

```
df['column3'] = [i[j - 1] for i, j in zip(df.column1, df.column2)]

df    
  column1  column2 column3
0  abcdef        2       b
1   gtihj        4       h
2   jiuwq        3       u
```

This problem is fundamentally difficult to vectorize, so a list comprehension operating at C-speed is a very performant alternative.

Slower alternatives include (for the sake of completeness), `apply`,

```
df['column3'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.column1[x.column2 - 1], 1)

df    
  column1  column2 column3
0  abcdef        2       b
1   gtihj        4       h
2   jiuwq        3       u
```

And `np.vectorize`:

```
f = np.vectorize(lambda x, y: x[y - 1])
df['column3'] = f(df.column1, df.column2)

df
  column1  column2 column3
0  abcdef        2       b
1   gtihj        4       h
2   jiuwq        3       u
```

Comment: @deega Great, I'm happy to hear that.

Answer (score 2):

Stretching the imagination to vectorize here...
This is more trouble than it's worth.  Use cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's comprehension.
How this post adds value is that it validates that it is non trivial to do in a better way.

```
slc = np.append(
    0, df.column1.str.len().values[:-1].cumsum()
) + df.column2.values - 1

df.assign(column3=np.array(list(''.join(df.column1)))[slc])

  column1  column2 column3
0  abcdef        2       b
1   gtihj        4       h
2   jiuwq        3       u
```